# Invalid Date in Firefox using .toLocaleString() as well as moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, firefox, momentjs

I have a script that I am attempting to convert a UTC date/time to local timezone. It all seems to be working well in Chrome and IE/Edge, but shows "invalid date" in Firefox. There are several other questions out there on stack but none seem to address my specific need.

My script does this...

Gets a date that is a specific format put out by Fabrik in Joomla. (I have little control over this format)

it looks like this:

```
2017-07-02 20:57
```

And then I create a new date as UTC and convert that to a Local timezone.

toLocalString method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.plg-date > .fabrikElement > div').not('.fabrikSubElementContainer').each(function() {
            if($(this).text().length > 0) {
                var newdate = new Date($(this).text() + " UTC");
                var options = { 
                    year: 'numeric', 
                    month: 'numeric', 
                    day: 'numeric',
                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    timeZoneName: 'short'
                }
                $(this).text(newdate.toLocaleString('en-US', options)); 
            }
        })
    });
```

moment.js method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plg-date > .fabrikElement > div').not('.fabrikSubElementContainer').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().length > 0) {
            var date = new Date($(this).text() + " UTC");
            var newdate = moment(date).format('ddd MMM DD YYYY h:mm A')
            $(this).text(newdate);
        }
    })
});
```

both methods result in invalid date in firefox. suggestions?

Comment: Create the date instance with Moment and an explicit format describing the date strings you've got. That's the only safe thing to do; browsers do whatever they want when you give them a string that's not in the spec.

Comment: If you feed the Moment library with a `Date` object you've already created by yourself, you aren't going to benefit from Moment's date parsing features. Either stick to Moment or drop it entirely.

Comment: Changing " UTC" to "Z" or "+00:00" should work, as those generate accepted ISO8601 date strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using moment you can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) and [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/):

```
var newdate = moment.utc($(this).text()).local().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY h:mm A')
```

[`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) parses your input as UTC value, while [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) converts it to local time.

Comment: On quickie, how do i display the timezone the time has been converted to if possible?

Comment: @SandraWillford You can use `Z` and `ZZ` tokens in [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get UTC offset (e.g. `+02:00`), while using `z` to get timezone abbreviation is deprecated and could be used only with moment-timezone (More info in the timezone section of the [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method).

Answer (score 2):

Your format strings don't match what either API needs. You are currently passing the text (`2017-07-02 20:57`) with `UTC` appended to the end (i.e. `2017-07-02 20:57 UTC`). In a javascript console:

```
new Date("2017-07-02 20:57");
Date 2017-07-02T19:57:00.000Z
new Date("2017-07-02 20:57 UTC")
Invalid Date
```

It *should* work if you drop the `UTC` component. Notice, though, that javascript is turning `20:57` into `19:57`. This is because of daylight savings, which might occur on a client's computer. Whether this affects your app depends on where the timestamps are coming from.

As for the moment example you gave, your format string should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` for your input string.

Comment: Yea, I've tried dropping the UTC component and it does get rid of the invalid date, however it then outputs 20:57 as 8:57 EDT where it the desired output would be 4:57 EDT.

Comment: That's where the timezone component of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) comes in. The browser is assuming that the date is using the same timezone as the client's computer. You will need to add timezone information to your timestamp in order for it to shift correctly (I believe).